# How to populate a Highchart graph with Angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

I want to populate a Highchart graph with the answer of a REST controller, here is the typescript part of the Angular9 component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-device-graph',
  templateUrl: './device-graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./device-graph.component.scss']
})
export class DeviceGraphComponent implements OnInit {
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Voltage'
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Input voltage'
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9],
          [Date.UTC(2010, 2, 1), 71.5],
          [Date.UTC(2010, 3, 1), 106.4]
        ],
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Vin1'
      },
      {
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 39.9],
          [Date.UTC(2010, 2, 1), 91.5],
          [Date.UTC(2010, 3, 1), 96.4]
        ],
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Vin2'
      }
    ]
  };

  data: String[] = [];
  isLoadingResults = true;

  constructor(private api: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.api.getInputVoltage('10.1.30.1').subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        this.chartOptions.series.data[0]=res;
        this.data = res;
        //console.log(this.data);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
        Highcharts.chart('container', this.chartOptions);
      },
      err => {
        //console.log(err);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The code contains hard coded data for testing purpouses, but is supposed to be replaced with the response to the GET API (which is already implemented). The JSON format is similar to the hard coded data: timestamp and an array of values.

When I try to compile it, I get these errors:

```
[INFO] ERROR in src/main/webapp/app/device-graph/device-graph.component.ts:54:9 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
[INFO] 
[INFO] 54         this.chartOptions.series.data[0]=res;
[INFO]            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO] src/main/webapp/app/device-graph/device-graph.component.ts:54:34 - error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SeriesOptionsType[]'.
[INFO] 
[INFO] 54         this.chartOptions.series.data[0]=res;
[INFO]                                     ~~~~
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is my JSON, but the issue is that the code above don't even compile https://pastebin.com/D6MBG2dW

Comment: Could you please provide a sample response from the API?

Comment: I write also the back end, so I can tweak the API if necessary. My problem is that it doesn't compile the front end

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you exactly want to update, but it looks like `this.chartOptions.series` is an array. So you might have to do `this.chartOptions.series[0].data[0]=res`.

**OR**

Maybe you receive the complete data array from the API. In that case, to update the first data, you need to do `this.chartOptions.series[0].data=res`. It all depends what data you receive from the backend and what you wish to update in the chart.

Comment: src/main/webapp/app/device-graph/device-graph.component.ts:54:37 - error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SeriesOptionsType'.
[INFO]   Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SeriesAbandsOptions'.

Comment: My problem is that it doesn't compile the front end

Comment: I couldn't find `SeriesAbandsOptions` in the code you've posted so far. Could you please post the code where `SeriesAbandsOptions` is used or defined? I'd also be helpful if you posted the JSON response you get from the API.

Comment: I don't have any code about SeriesAbandsOptions, I assume that's part of the Highcharts. My JSON currently is this https://pastebin.com/D6MBG2dW , but I don't think is relevant at this stage.

Comment: Indeed it's part of Highcharts code, you can find it here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist/master/highcharts.d.ts